# Functions cannot be passed directly to Client Components

Tags: next.js, next.js14

I am using next js 14.0.3, when i passed the icon from server component to client componet its gives my this error

*'Functions cannot be passed directly to Client Components unless you explicitly expose it by marking it with "use server".'*

this is server component

```
import React from "react";
import { Layout, Compass } from "lucide-react";
import SidebarItem from "./SidebarItem";

const guestRoutes = [
  {
    label: "Home",
    path: "/",
    icon: Layout,
  },
  {
    label: "Browse",
    path: "/search",
    icon: Compass,
  },
];

function SidebarRoutes() {
  const routes = guestRoutes;

  return (
    <div className="flex mt-4 flex-col h-full">
      {routes.map((route) => {
        return (
          <SidebarItem
            key={route.path}
            icon={route.icon}
            label={route.label}
            path={route.path}
          />
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}

export default SidebarRoutes;
```

and this is clinet component

```
'use client';

import React from "react";
import { LucideIcon } from "lucide-react";
import { usePathname, useRouter } from "next/navigation";

interface SidebarItemProps {
  label: string;
  path: string;
  icon: LucideIcon;
}
const SidebarItem = ({ label, icon: Icon, path }: SidebarItemProps) => {
  const router = useRouter();
  const pathname = usePathname();

  return (
    <Icon/>
  );
};

export default SidebarItem;
```

anyone know how can i fix it

I have to check the path name for conidional rendering thats why i need to convert this component into client side, I tried but not fixing